Path is not a valid JDT verb
Trying to use SlowCheetah by Microsoft to introduce transforms of my appSettings file to one per build.
Whenever I build though Visual Studio is giving me this error
path is not a valid JDT verb

My json files
appSettings.json
"Connectivity": {
    "Host": "original"
  }

appSettings.Debug.json
{
  "@jdt.path" : "Connectivity.Host",
  "@jdt.value": "something"
}

I don't exactly understand what the problem is and searching online wasn't much help.

I've never seen JDT before but... This doc suggests the only verbs are Rename, Remove, Merge, and Replace. It looks like you're trying to do a Replace, so according to this the syntax would be { "Connectivity": { "@jdt.replace": { "Host": "something" } } }?

Although according to this, just { "Connectivity": { "Host": "something" } } would work?

In the same place you are I saw this
https://github.com/microsoft/json-document-transforms/wiki/Transform-Attributes
but, let me try your example in case that works

@canton7 wait, I can just put the new values without any logic? That's ideal, ok trying both

This post makes it look like the path stuff has to be inside a verb, which I guess makes some sort of sense

@canton7 Ah, so it's the verb and then the path, ok, but in the end of the day, just copying the same value in the Debug json file (I mean the whole object with a new value) it replaces it automatically, so, not even a need for transforming stuff using JDT. Thanks though

As pointed out by canton7 in the comments of the question, using transformation verbs at all but in fact, just adding
  {
    "Connectivity": {
      "Host": "something"
    }
  }

and the value will be replaced in the main appSettings.json file during build. Link to Github docs explaining the default transformations.
